# Use regex to exclude the homepage "/"

Tags: regex

I am trying to exclude the homepage of a site i.e. "/" from my Google Analytics report
e.g. exclude (/category1|category2) and also exclude the homepage that comes up in my reports as "/"

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried? I know GA does not support lookarounds. I'm pretty sure you can include the urls you want to exclude via Filters -> Exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a regex `(/category1|category2)` matches `/category1` and `category2`. It sounds like you want something like `/(category[12])?` which matches `/`, `/category1` and `/category2`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex that matches `/` is:

```
^/$
```

You could combine that with other things:

```
^/|/category1|/category2$
```